# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 60

Tags: php, parsing

I don't why i get this error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitelinks\top_links.php on line 60**

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitelinks\top_links.php on line 60

```
 <div id="topbar">
    <div id="navigation" class="ddsmoothmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/index.php" class="main">Home</a></li>
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
            <li><a href="/services" class="main">Servizi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/services/?p=details" class="sub">Profilo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/services/?p=atcdocs" class="sub">Documentazione ATC</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/services/?p=pildocs" class="sub">Documentazione PILOTI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Membri</a></li>

                </ul>
                <? } ?>
            </li>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
            <li><a href="#" class="main">Members</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                </ul>
                <? } ?>
            </li>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
            <li><a href="#" class="main">Databases</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                </ul>
                <? } ?>
            </li>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
            <li><a href="#" class="main">Divisions</a>
              <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <? } ?>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
            <li><a href="#" class="main">Airlines</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="sub">Put a link here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <? } ?>
            <li><a href="#" class="main">Forum</a></li>
        </ul>
        <? if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
    <? } else { ?>
        <a href="/?p=login" class="login">Login</a>
        <? } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me??

Thank youuuuu

Comment: You are missing a brace somewhere.

Comment: try to use <?php instead of short open tags

Comment: a advice use `<?php if(isset($somevar)): ?>` YOUR HTML `<?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Another suggestion: try setting a variable to test existence of  `$_SESSION['login']`.  Something like `$is_logged_in = isset($_SESSION['login']);`.  Then you can just go `if ($is_logged_in) ....`

Comment: try `echo ini_get('short_open_tag') ? 'true' : 'false'`.  looks like a short tag problem

Comment: replace all `<?` -> `<?php` as B.Bridge said =)

Comment: Thanks guys..  For Example:

     <ul>
            <li><a href="/index.php" class="main">Home</a></li>
               <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])): ?>
            <li><a href="/services" class="main">Servizi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/services/?p=pildocs" class="sub">Documentazione PILOTI</a></li>

                </ul>
               <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473654/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file-php.

Answer (score 3):

By replacing every occurrence of `<?` with `<?php` the script parses fine, so it seems to be the case that you have the `short_open_tag` set to off. You can either turn it on in you php.ini file (you can't use `ini_set`), or switch to using the full open tag (which I'd recommend as that allows you, for example, to use `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` in your HTML files without having to `echo` it.).